# MVC 5 C# Search a Many-to-Many Relational Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a database with academic publications, which all have multiple authors. I have a page that displays a paged partial view of these publications, with multiple filtering options, designed to use multiple filters simultaneously.

I've been able to implement all of the other filtering options just fine, but the one that's giving me trouble is the filter by author(s), where users can type in an author's name and it will return any publications from that author.

It's a code-first database, and the publications model contains this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
```

And likewise, in the Author model:

```
public virtual ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
```

Right now, I have the controller returning a partial view like so:

```
Models.Author[] auth = db.Authors.Where(p => p.FullName.ToLower()
    .Contains(searchAuthor).ToLower())).ToArray();

return PartialView("_PublicationList", await db.Publications
    .Where(p => p.Authors.ToList().Contains(auth[0])).ToListAsync());
```

where "searchAuthor" is the value in the text box from the view (I'm leaving out the other filters for simplicity).

As you can see, this only searches the first author that matches. If someone types "Michael", and there are more than one Michael who have contributed, it will only show search results for the first Michael.

So, how should I go about this? I've been searching Google for days, and I haven't found a solution for returning a partial view with multiple publications and multiple authors. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: So you want to get all publications for all authors that match your 'searchAuthor'?

Comment: Sorry, not that match exactly, but that contain the string in their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to switch your `p.Authors.ToList().Contains(auth[0])` so that it uses all the values returned by `auth`

Something like this should work:

```
return PartialView("_PublicationList", await db.Publications
.Where(p => p.Authors.Any(a => auth.Contains(a)).ToListAsync());
```

In English: "List of publications where the list of that publication's authors has a match in the searchAuthor list"

Comment: Real answer was deleted because they thought this answer was correct; however, the final code was slightly different. I didn't need the `auth` variable, so this answer is misleading for anyone searching this problem. The correct answer was the one I posted afterwards, which has the following code: `... .Where(p => p.Authors.Any(a => a.name.Contains(searchAuthor))) ...`